# Modes of convergence tests for a given sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ be independent random variables with $P(Y_n =-3)=\frac{1}{n}$, $P(Y_n =1)=1-\frac{3}{n}$ and $P(Y_n = 3)=\frac{2}{n}$. I am investigating the various modes of convergence for the above sequence. Can anyone check if the following are correct?

I first claim that $Y_n \to^{\mathrm{mean}} 1$. To show it, notice that $|Y_n - 1|$ can take values of 4 (with probability $\frac{1}{n}$), 0 (with probability $1-\frac{3}{n}$) or 2 (with probability $\frac{2}{n}$). Thus $E(|Y_n - 1|) = \frac{4}{n}+0+\frac{4}{n}=\frac{8}{n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

I then claim that $Y_n \to^{\mathrm{dist'n}} Y$. Now, the random variable $Y_n$ has cumulative distribution function $$F_{Y_n}(y)=P(Y_n\leqslant y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
0 & y <-3\\
\frac{1}{n} & -3\leqslant y<1\\
1-\frac{2}{n} & 1\leqslant y<3\\
1 & y\geqslant 3
\end{array}
\right.$$
As $n\to\infty$ the c.d.f tends towards the c.d.f
$$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leqslant y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
0 & y<1\\
1 & y\geqslant 1\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then the random variable $Y$ has p.d.f
$$f_Y(y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1 & y=1\\
0 & y\neq 1
\end{array}
\right.$$

If I were to also investigate whether the sequence is convergent almost surely, is it sufficient to only consider whether $Y_n \to^{\mathrm{as}} 1$, as 1 seems the most likely candidate from the given probabilities?

Comment: How did you check that $1$ is not the a.s. limit of $Y_n$? Suppose there were  some a.s. limit $Y$.  What do you know about $Y$? Do you know the zero-one law, or the dominated convergence theorem, or the converse to Borel-Cantelli?  You might be able to use some subset of them to impeach the putative a.s. limit $Y$.

Comment: I'm familiar with all the theorems you have cited, but I was wondering how you would use them (or any other method) to show that no such $Y$ is possible.

Comment: By the 0-1 law, the putative limit $Y$ is a constant.  By dominated convergence, it has the wrong mean.

Comment: That's more helpful, but could you please explain why the 0-1 law shows the limit is constant?

Comment: I meant the Kolmogorov 0-1 law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law). If $Y_n\to Y$ a.s., the r.v. $Y$ is measurable with respect to the tail field. That is, a.s. constant.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you

Comment: Is the rest of my investigation ok for the other modes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63414/discussion-between-kimchi-lover-and-will).

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\{Y_n\}$ converges in probability to $1$, as for any $0<\varepsilon<1$ we have $$\{|Y_n-1| <\varepsilon\} = \{Y_n = 1\}$$ and hence
$$\mathbb P(|Y_n-1|<\varepsilon) = \mathbb P(Y_n = 1) = 1 - \frac3n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow1. $$
Indeed, the sequence converges in $L^1$, as 
$$\mathbb E[|Y_n-1|] = 4\cdot\frac1n + 0 + 2\cdot\frac2n =\frac8n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0. $$
The sequence does not converge almost surely, however, as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(Y_n\ne 1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac3n=+\infty, $$
so by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{Y_n\ne1\}\right) = 1. $$